# return origin color values of a picture

Tags: java, image, colors

I'm doing an assignment about editing picture in java. The assignment asks to make a code changing an image's colors into 3 different shades and animate it so it'll be like a GIF. I completed the tasks but somehow when it change between the shades the picture get loose of detail and leave out just a blue blank color on the third shade change. I tried add a code return the color value to origin before changing the next one but still this issue happen. Might be I get the code wrong. Can someone help me with this.

```
/* Assignment 3, Part 1 - Go Psychedelic! */

public class Assignment3Part1
{
//
  public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    String filename;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      // got a filename passed into program as a parameter
      // don't change this part of the code needed by TA for grading
      filename = args[0];      
      System.out.println("Filename passed in: " + filename);

    } else {
      // ask user for a picture
      filename = FileChooser.pickAFile();
      System.out.println("User picked file: " + filename);
    }
    Picture pic = new Picture(filename);   // Picture to modify
    //
    pic.show();             // Show the original picture
    Thread.sleep(1000);     //  Pause for 1 second.  You can pause for less if you like

    // TODO: insert method call to tint your picture
    pic.tintRed(50);

    pic.repaint();          // Show the tinted picture
    Thread.sleep(1000);     //  Pause for 1 second

    // TODO: insert method call to tint your picture
    pic.tintRed(-50);
    pic.tintGreen(20);

    pic.repaint();          // Show the tinted picture
    Thread.sleep(1000);     //  Pause for 1 second

    // TODO: insert method call to tint your picture
    pic.tintGreen(0);
    pic.tintBlue(10);

    pic.repaint();          // Show the tinted picture
    Thread.sleep(1000);     //  Pause for 1 second

  }  // End of main method

}  // End of class
```

Codes for the method

```
  public void tintRed(int percent)
  {
    Pixel[] pixelArray = this.getPixels();
    Pixel pixel = null;
    int value = 0;
    int i = 0;

    //loop through all the pixels in the array
    while (i<pixelArray.length)
    {
      // get the current pixel
      pixel = pixelArray[i];
      // get the value
      value = pixel.getRed();
      // set the value to % of what it was
      pixel.setRed((int)(value*percent));
      // increment the index
      i++;
    }
  }
```

Same for Blue and Green values

Answer (score 0):

You are saturating the colors to a point where everything is 100% a color (a blank picture). You have to play with your shading algorithm to be more gentle: like 25%, 50%, 75% for instance

Comment: I kinda get what you mean. As I see the problem is about the percentage value. I just added a line to it so it now something like value*(percentage/100). Yes it brings the more exact result to the task. but now the tintRed not work somehow lol. Can u help me w that too?